# Google Chart: How to avoid disappearing of annotations on each chart in dashboard control?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart", 'bar', 'Controls']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var chartsdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  chartsdata.addColumn('date', 'Datum');
  chartsdata.addColumn('number', 'TijdAfd1');
  chartsdata.addColumn({
    'type': 'string',
    'role': 'annotation'
  });
  chartsdata.addColumn('number', 'TijdAfd2');
  chartsdata.addColumn({
    'type': 'string',
    'role': 'annotation'
  });
  chartsdata.addColumn('number', 'TijdAfd3');
  chartsdata.addColumn({
    'type': 'string',
    'role': 'annotation'
  });

  chartsdata.addRows([
    [new Date('2017-05-29'), 56, '7,3m³', 42, '5,7m³', 59, '9524m³'],
    [new Date('2017-05-30'), 29, '3,8m³', 23, '3,1m³', 30, '4746m³'],
    [new Date('2017-05-31'), 53, '6,9m³', 13, '1,8m³', 60, '9522m³'],
    [new Date('2017-06-01'), 47, '6,1m³', 45, '6,2m³', 53, '8463m³'],
    [new Date('2017-06-02'), 69, '9,1m³', 48, '6,7m³', 66, '10502m³'],
    [new Date('2017-06-03'), 39, '5,1m³', 25, '3,4m³', 41, '6604m³'],
    [new Date('2017-06-04'), 51, '6,7m³', 44, '6,0m³', 43, '6800m³']
  ]);

  // Create a dashboard.
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
    document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

  // Create a range slider, passing some options
  var ChartRangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'filter_div',
    options: {
      //displayLabels: false,
      //displayAnnotations: false,
      tooltip: {
        isHtml: true
      },
      filterColumnLabel: 'Datum',
      ui: {
        chartOptions: {
          height: 55
        }
      }
    },
    // exclude annotation columns
    view: {
      columns: [0, 1, 3, 5]
    }
  });

  // Create a Column chart, passing some options
  var ColumnChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'ColumnChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    options: {
      focusTarget: 'category',
      tooltip: {
        isHtml: true
      }
    }
  });

  // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'ColumnChart',
  // so that the column chart will only display entries that are let through
  // given the chosen slider range.
  dashboard.bind(ChartRangeFilter, ColumnChart);

  // Draw the dashboard.
  dashboard.draw(chartsdata);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="dashboard_div">
  <!--Divs that will hold each control and chart-->
  <div id="filter_div"></div>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
```

I’ve added a dashboard control and bind a ChartRangeFilter and ColumnChart to it. If I configure a view on the ChartRangeFilter  to exclude the columns used for the annotation, then those annotations are also disappearing from my ColumnChart. Setting the displayAnnotations to false on the ChartRangeFilter doesn’t change anything.

```
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart", 'bar', 'Controls'] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("AjaxMethod", "AcuatorsRunTimes")',
        data: { StartDate: "@ViewData["StartDate"]", EndDate: "@ViewData["EndDate"]" },
        success: function (Data) {

            var data1 = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(Data);


            var chartsdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            chartsdata.addColumn('date', 'Datum');
            chartsdata.addColumn({ 'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip', 'p': { 'html': true } });
            chartsdata.addColumn('number', 'TijdAfd1');
            //chartsdata.addColumn('string', "VolumeAfd1");
            chartsdata.addColumn({ 'type': 'string', 'role': 'annotation' });
            chartsdata.addColumn('number', 'TijdAfd2');
            //chartsdata.addColumn('string', "VolumeAfd2");
            chartsdata.addColumn({ 'type': 'string', 'role': 'annotation' });
            chartsdata.addColumn('number', 'TijdAfd3');
            //chartsdata.addColumn('string', "VolumeAfd3");
            chartsdata.addColumn({ 'type': 'string', 'role': 'annotation' });

            for (var i = 1; i < data1.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {

                var myDate = Date.parse(data1.getFormattedValue(i, 0));
                var titles = ['Afdeling 1', 'Afdeling 2', 'Afdeling 3'];
                var values = [data1.getFormattedValue(i, 4), data1.getFormattedValue(i, 5), data1.getFormattedValue(i, 6)];
                var Anno1 = data1.getFormattedValue(i, 7) + 'm³';
                var Anno2 = data1.getFormattedValue(i, 8) + 'm³';
                var Anno3 = data1.getFormattedValue(i, 9) + 'm³';
                chartsdata.addRow([new Date(myDate), HTMLtableRows(titles, values), parseInt(data1.getFormattedValue(i, 1)), Anno1, parseInt(data1.getFormattedValue(i, 2)), Anno2, parseInt(data1.getFormattedValue(i, 3)), Anno3]);
            }

            // Create a dashboard.
            var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
                document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

            // Create a range slider, passing some options
            var ChartRangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
                containerId: 'filter_div',
                options: {
                    //displayLabels: false,
                    //displayAnnotations: false,
                    tooltip: { isHtml: true },
                    filterColumnLabel: 'Datum',
                    ui: {
                        chartType: 'LineChart',
                        chartOptions: {
                            height: 55
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            // Create a column chart, passing some options
            var ColumnChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                chartType: 'ColumnChart',
                containerId: 'chart_div',
                options: {
                    focusTarget: 'category',
                    tooltip: { isHtml: true }
                }
            });

            // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'ColumnChart',
            // so that the column chart will only display entries that are let through
            // given the chosen slider range.
            dashboard.bind(ChartRangeFilter, ColumnChart);

            // Draw the dashboard.
            dashboard.draw(chartsdata);

        },
        failure: function (Data) {
            alert(Data.d);
        },
        error: function (Data) {
            alert(Data.d);
        }
    });
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsLLF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*include* the annotation columns in the data table used to draw the dashboard,

then *exclude* those columns from the `view` property on the filter...

```
var ChartRangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'filter_div',
    options: {
        tooltip: { isHtml: true },
        filterColumnLabel: 'Datum',
        ui: {
            chartType: 'LineChart',
            chartOptions: {
                height: 55
            }
        }
    },
    // exclude annotation columns
    view: {
      columns: [0, 1, 2, 4, 6]
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

hide the annotations on the range filter by making them transparent,
add the following to `chartOptions`...

```
          annotations: {
            highContrast: false,
            stem: {
              color: 'transparent',
              length: 0
            },
            textStyle: {
              color: 'transparent'
            }
          },
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart", 'bar', 'Controls']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var chartsdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  chartsdata.addColumn('date', 'Datum');
  chartsdata.addColumn('number', 'TijdAfd1');
  chartsdata.addColumn({
    'type': 'string',
    'role': 'annotation'
  });
  chartsdata.addColumn('number', 'TijdAfd2');
  chartsdata.addColumn({
    'type': 'string',
    'role': 'annotation'
  });
  chartsdata.addColumn('number', 'TijdAfd3');
  chartsdata.addColumn({
    'type': 'string',
    'role': 'annotation'
  });

  chartsdata.addRows([
    [new Date('2017-05-29'), 56, '7,3m³', 42, '5,7m³', 59, '9524m³'],
    [new Date('2017-05-30'), 29, '3,8m³', 23, '3,1m³', 30, '4746m³'],
    [new Date('2017-05-31'), 53, '6,9m³', 13, '1,8m³', 60, '9522m³'],
    [new Date('2017-06-01'), 47, '6,1m³', 45, '6,2m³', 53, '8463m³'],
    [new Date('2017-06-02'), 69, '9,1m³', 48, '6,7m³', 66, '10502m³'],
    [new Date('2017-06-03'), 39, '5,1m³', 25, '3,4m³', 41, '6604m³'],
    [new Date('2017-06-04'), 51, '6,7m³', 44, '6,0m³', 43, '6800m³']
  ]);

  // Create a dashboard.
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
    document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

  // Create a range slider, passing some options
  var ChartRangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'filter_div',
    options: {
      //displayLabels: false,
      //displayAnnotations: false,
      tooltip: {
        isHtml: true
      },
      filterColumnLabel: 'Datum',
      ui: {
        chartOptions: {
          annotations: {
            highContrast: false,
            stem: {
              color: 'transparent',
              length: 0
            },
            textStyle: {
              color: 'transparent'
            }
          },
          height: 55
        }
      }
    }
  });

  // Create a Column chart, passing some options
  var ColumnChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'ColumnChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    options: {
      focusTarget: 'category',
      tooltip: {
        isHtml: true
      }
    }
  });

  // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'ColumnChart',
  // so that the column chart will only display entries that are let through
  // given the chosen slider range.
  dashboard.bind(ChartRangeFilter, ColumnChart);

  // Draw the dashboard.
  dashboard.draw(chartsdata);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="dashboard_div">
  <!--Divs that will hold each control and chart-->
  <div id="filter_div"></div>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've updated the javascript so it is executable. I've also added WhiteHat suggestions to exclude the annotation from the ChartRangeFilter. But then also the annotations on the ColumnChart are disappearing, what the original problem was. Is there a possibility to only hide the annotations from the ChartRangeFilter?